# RCov with JRuby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, tdd, rcov

I have a project I want to get code coverage on. It's just a standard JRuby project not on Rails and I was wondering how to get RCov to work. I have been trying for a long time to get results and I just don't know whats going on. I get a coverage folder to get displayed but all the files either get loaderrors on requires or the files that get loaded just don't say they've been tested at all (which I know in one case is balooney since I made a test spec for it). Can anyone explain to me how to get RCov to work or why I am getting the attached error? I don't understand how/why you are supposed to do a -I for included libraries or what the point of that is. From what I've been doing so far I have been just running rcov spec/*.rb from my main appcode directory and that generates my coverage folder and :
 rcov spec/*.rb
/home/ben/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rcov-0.9.11-java/lib/rcov/differential_analyzer.rb:31 warning: tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug flag
NoMethodError: undefined method `describe' for main:Object
  (root) at ./spec/ncrf_spec.rb:3

Comment: Do running RCov from RSec work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058676/rcov-with-rspec-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RCov](https://github.com/relevance/rcov) is strictly limited to [Matz's reference implemenation](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) of Ruby (MRI) 1.8.x and doesn't even work on MRI 1.9.x.

SimpleCov is the new way to go, as it uses the new [Ruby Coverage API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/coverage/rdoc/Coverage.html). This API for a while was not supported by JRuby, or at least not to an extent that it was usable in production. The [original issue on SimpleCov's bugtracker](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/86) doesn't state explicitly that it works now. However, [the issue they files in the JRuby tracker](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6106?focusedCommentId=307044#comment-307044) about this Ruby Coverage API not working correctly states that this issue is now resolved.

I guess you should try your luck with the latest versions of both JRuby and SimpleCov.

On the other topic:

Ruby's `-I` flag adds directories to the `$LOAD_PATH` array which defines the locations in which `.rb` files are searched when you try to load them with `require`. As of Ruby 1.9.x files can only be found when they are in one of the directories in `$LOAD_PATH` and are no longer also found relative to the current working directory of your Ruby process.

Comment: I didn't know RCov was limited to 1.8.x, thanks for the tip on SimpleCov!